# Unusual issue with virtual backgrounds on Zoom

Tags: zoom-meeting

I guess I'm only *assuming* that it's unusual, perhaps not, I don't know.
I have a green screen that certainly improved my virtual background but "unfortunately" I have green eyes so they are being treated as the green screen.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/5WCium1fzXpmsqzk8

Comment: Then you need a different colour backdrop.

Comment: (Or assign an exclusion zone for the background but I have no idea if Zoom supports something like that)